# Word for the state of being compelled

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a way to describe the state of having an intense driver or urge for a thing. I could only think of "compellement" but I fear it is not a word, or the state of being compelled exists in a different form than what I can guess.

An example of what I want to communicate would be "As opposed to doing it out of addiction, he did it out of compellment for the art".

Comment: The noun from 'compel' is 'compulsion'.

Comment: Under some circumstances, **ensorcelled** may be used. https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ensorcelled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question:

> I could only think of "compellement" but I fear it is not a word, or the state of being compelled exists in a different form than what I can guess.

As was stated in a comment under the question, the noun is not *compellment*, but [**compulsion**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compulsion):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1 a** : an act of compelling
>   // tried to get them to cooperate without using *compulsion*
>   : the state of being compelled
>   // He was acting under *compulsion*.
>   **1 b** : a force that compels
>   **2** : an irresistible persistent impulse to perform an act (such as excessive hand washing)
>   // her *compulsion* to repeatedly check and recheck the stove to be certain that it is turned off
>   *also* : the act itself
>   // Gambling is a *compulsion* with him.

So, the example sentence becomes:

> As opposed to doing it out of addiction, he did it out of [a] *compulsion* for the art".

Comment: Compulsion! Of course! How could I miss it!

Answer (score 2):

If you mean being compelled to do something by some internal force, rather than an external force, then *driven* is as good as anything.

> **driven** adjective
>
> Someone who is driven is so determined to achieve something or be successful that all of their behaviour is directed towards this aim:
>
> *Like most of the lawyers that I know, Rachel is driven.*

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/driven)

Answer (score 1):

An option would be [dedication](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dedication):

> the willingness to give a lot of time and energy to something because it is important

An additional example (from the source):

> She applied herself to the task with enormous energy and dedication.

Answer (score 0):

One word is **passion** about which [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/passion) says

> **passion**
>   NOUN
>
> Strong and barely controllable emotion.
>   *As opposed to doing it out of addiction, he did it out of **a passion for** the art*

Another word is **devotion** about which [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/devotion) says

> **devotion**
>   NOUN
>
> Love, loyalty, or enthusiasm for a person or activity.
>   *As opposed to doing it out of addiction, he did it out of **devotion to** the art*